# Monitoring delay in Firebase integration to BigQuery using Stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, stackdriver

I have a Firebase project integrated with BigQuery.
Each morning (local time based on time zone settings in Firebase) the near-real-time data stream is taken from the intraday table to the main events table.
This happens after a signal managed by Google and can sometime be a little unreliable (i.e. be executed with several hours of delay on the usual time of 6-7AM): this affects our ability to generate early morning reports.

I was trying to use Stackdriver to setup an alert that would trigger if this job was jot started by 8AM.
However exploring the metrics I couldn't find one where I could define such a condition.
Most metrics I tried let you define a threshold which is a control on the y-axis, while in my case the control would need to be on the time x-axis.

is it possible to do something like that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the various notification options provided by Cloud Monitoring. This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options) lists supported notification channel types and provides an explanation on how to configure them through the Cloud Console. It can be done through the Cloud Monitoring API as well, more information through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-channels-api#api-create-channels).

This article [here](https://www.thagomizer.com/blog/2017/02/23/monitoring-bigquery-with-stackdriver.html) provides a brief overview and user perspective of Monitoring BigQuery with Stackdriver, that I suggest you have a look at.